# How to deal with name conflicts in Racket?

Tags: package, racket, conflict

While learning Racket, I came across the [gregor](https://docs.racket-lang.org/gregor/date.html) package which says that its `date` struct conflicts with the built-in `date` struct:

> Gregor provides a date struct that represents a calendar date without
>   a time or time zone. Unfortunately, the name date conflicts with an
>   existing, incompatible definition in racket/base.

Before I do a `(require gregor)`, I get the built-in `date`. After `(require gregor)`, I get gregor's date. That's fine.

But, in the interest of understanding how to deal with conflicts and namespaces, is it possible for me to access the built-in `date`? Can I somehow put gregor into a namespace so I can use both?  What's the idiomatic way of dealing with this?

Answer (score 3):

You can rename each required ids to make them not conflict.

```
(require (rename-in gregor [date gregor-date]))
date ;; Racket's date
gregor-date ;; gregor's date
```

But a quick solution would be prefixing every required ids (which creates the "namespace" in a sense)

```
(require (prefix-in gregor: gregor))
date ;; Racket's date
gregor:date ;; gregor's date
```

See https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/require.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._prefix-in%29%29

Answer (score 2):

First off `require` overrides the base package the languages imported. Thus unlike standard Scheme where you need to rename or exclude from the base package you can `require` and as long the conflicting name is not from another `require` it works.

Imagine I use `#!racket/base` througout as the language. So lets imagine you want to do this:

```
(require racket) ; now date it will conflict
(require gregor)
```

I just press run and see whats happening. So I got an error that `date?` was a conflict and I choose to omit it:

```
(require (except-in racket/base date?)) 
(require gregor)
```

I still got the conflict `date` so I just add it to the exception:

```
(require (except-in racket date? date)) 
(require gregor)
```

Now we have something that works, but you cannot use `date?` and `date` from `racket`
Now if you want to be able to use both you might want to add a prefix:

```
(require (prefix-in rb: racket))
(require gregor)
```

This will make a binding like `rb:date` as the `racket/base` one, but it will also have `rb:second` etc. If you just want to rename `date?` and `date` I would have done this:

```
(require (rename-in racket [date? rb:date?] [date rb:date]))
(require gregor)
```

Like this we have `date?` and `date` as `rb:date?` and `rb:date` while keeping all the other bindings like `second` as is.

You can mix and match and usually you choose the easiest solution for providing exactly what you want. More ways to do this in the codumentation for [`require`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/require.html?q=provide#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._require%29%29) and [`provide`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/require.html?q=provide#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._provide%29%29)